# No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location

Tags: android, appcelerator

I tried using Titanium for the first time, but even if I keep giving him the path to my SDK folder, it tells me that it doesn't found it.

[image]

I created some user variables as I found on the net, but nothing works

```
ANDROID_SDK = D:\Program Files\Android SDK\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_SDK%/tools;%ANDROID_SDK%/platform
```

I also tried to follow this http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Errors_Configuring_Platforms_Inside_Studio but the log doesn't mention avd.py. So I try `ti sdk install --branch master 4.1.0.v20150417113624` but always the same problem.

Comment: Which titanium studio version you are using ?. if it is old then update the studio and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved :

I deleted the file at C:/Users//.titanium/config.json And I moved my android SDK folder. It seems it must be in C:/ drive on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. You answer guided me in the right direction.

In my case, I am using a Mac and I just needed to make sure that the zipalign path in ~/.titanium/config.json was pointing to the latest Android SDK that was installed (23.0.1). I have just set it to /Users/my_user_name/android-macosx-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign