# Android SDK Home: No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, android-sdk-2.3

I have tried many suggested solutions but could not resolve this issue, a few  links(solution) I am mentioning below:

1) https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/176318/alternative-solution-android-sdk-home-no-android-sdks-were-found-under-the-specified-sdk-location

2) [No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720919/no-android-sdks-were-found-under-the-specified-sdk-location)

and many more.

I am using Window 7, Appcelerator Studio 4.0.0, Titanium SDK 4.0.0GA

Thanks a lot for your help. I am trying almost last two days to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post this question community.appcelerator.com and provide the exact steps you took and the output of `appc ti config` then a support staff can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

I provided custom path in platform->android in appcelerator studio, may be that android sdk is corrupted, then I have given the suggested path by Appcelerator studio c->android-sdk and updated the sdk, then close the appcerator, opened it again and then magic happened. No there was no issue or error.

Hope it will help.